# Expo build crashes when building for android, despite gradlew succeeds build

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I've recently joined working on an existing project with one other dev. For some reason, I just can't succeed in building the project. I get the following error when running `npx expo run:android`:

```
    Error: C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
        at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
        at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
        at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
        at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
        at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
        ...
        at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
        at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
        at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
        at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\react-app\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:35:24)
        at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

However, when running

```
cd android
gradlew --stacktrace
```

the build succeeds. Furthermore, building the project works for my coworker, so I don't think the problem is with the code.

I have tried:

-Removing the android, npm, and expo folders

-Clearing npm and yarn caches

-Completely uninstalling any programs related even remotely to app development, including my IDE, SDKs, node Java, Android Studio,npm/yarn packages, yarn, npm, et cetera, and reinstalling everything from scratch to the same version of files my coworker has in an attempt to mimic his conditions.

If anyone has any idea how to fix this I would highly appreciate because I have not found anything useful online after several days of searching!

Comment: Have you find the cause of this issue? If so, can you please give an answer to this question?